# Shutting down VM while using handler inside fragment in Slide Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to show a dialog after 5 sec when fragment shows.So i used Handler in on Createview, but before showing dialog if i clicks to move in other fragment appcloses and also it doest show Force close. The app closes peacefully without error showing shutting down VM..I am using Slide drawer to move from one fragment to another.

Comment: logs are greatly appreciated

Comment: cant understand what you said?

Comment: provide us your log (logcat) to better understand what is your issue

Comment: 10-29 16:58:54.395  21059-21069/com.mtechno.freerechargeswipe W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 71.897ms
10-29 16:58:54.405  21059-21074/com.mtechno.freerechargeswipe I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4685(405KB) AllocSpace objects, 10(160KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 10MB/17MB, paused 2.079ms total 134.134ms
10-29 16:58:55.387  21059-21059/com.mtechno.freerechargeswipe D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-29 16:58:55.387  21059-21059/com.mtechno.freerechargeswipe I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 21059 SIG: 9